Dart Freezed package: Missing toJson method in generated file causing InvalidType error
I followed the documentation's step by step to add Freezed to a class:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'autonomy_event.freezed.dart';
part 'autonomy_event.g.dart';

@freezed
class AutonomyEvent with _$AutonomyEvent {
  const factory AutonomyEvent({
    required int eventCode,
    required int timestamp,
  }) = _AutonomyEvent;

  factory AutonomyEvent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AutonomyEventFromJson(json);
}

In Android Studio, I keep getting a InvalidType error at _$$AutonomyEventImplToJson in my generated freezed class autonomy_event.freezed.dart:
/// @nodoc
@JsonSerializable()
class _$AutonomyEventImpl implements _AutonomyEvent {

(...)

@override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return _$$AutonomyEventImplToJson(
      this,
    );
  }
}

The detailed error is:

The method '$$AutonomyEventImplToJson' isn't defined for the type
'$AutonomyEventImpl'. Try correcting the name to the
name of an existing method, or defining a method named
'_$$AutonomyEventImplToJson'.

I believe this error occurs due to autonomy_event.g.dart not generating the toJson method.
I tried adding @Freezed(toJson: true) instead of @freezed in my class file, however that didn't help as well, as the toJson method still isn't generated.

Alternative solution is make build.yaml in root level you can setting how to generate your model
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      freezed:freezed:
        generate_for:
          include:
            - lib/entity/** // Model folder path
      json_serializable:
        options:
          any_map: false
          checked: false
          constructor: ""
          create_factory: true
          create_to_json: true
          disallow_unrecognized_keys: false
          explicit_to_json: false
          field_rename: snake
          generic_argument_factories: false
          ignore_unannotated: false
          include_if_null: true

don't forget to add this in your dependencies
dev_dependencies:
  json_serializable:

Now when you run build runner it will generate every model by your setting without write @JsonSerializable(createToJson: true) to every model you have

To fix your issue, you need to add @JsonSerializable(createToJson: true) to your factory method.
When you do that, the ToJson method in your autonomy_event.g.dart will be generated, and the reference in autonomy_event.freezed.dart will be resolved.
Complete class code:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'autonomy_event.freezed.dart';
part 'autonomy_event.g.dart';

@freezed
class AutonomyEvent with _$AutonomyEvent {
  @JsonSerializable(createToJson: true)
  const factory AutonomyEvent({
    required int eventCode,
    required int timestamp,
  }) = _AutonomyEvent;

  factory AutonomyEvent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AutonomyEventFromJson(json);
}

